# Existence of a limiting sum of random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Consider that $X_i$‘s are independent exponentially distributed random variables with mean $1/i$ (and thus variance $1/i^2$).Then the sum of them seems to converge to a “random variable” with finite variance but unbounded mean. What’s the problem here? Why does not such random variable exist?
Thanks

Comment: By the same reasoning the "random variable" sequence $\{Y_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ defined by $Y_i=i$ for all $i$ (with prob 1) has partial sums $\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$ with _zero variance_ but mean that goes to infinity. But there is no mystery in this.  We certainly do not say that $\sum_{i=1}^n i$ "converges" in any sense (it diverges to $\infty$). [I put "random variable" in quotes simply because the $\{Y_i\}$ sequence is deterministic in this case.]

Answer (score 1):

Since $X_i$'s are positive $\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$ converges (to a possibly infinte ) sum $X$ and Monotone Convergence Theorem gives $EX=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac 1 i =\infty$. There is no way a random variable with infinite mean can have finite variance. It is not even true that $X <\infty$ almost surely. [This can be shown using Laplace transforms].